# R randomForest too many categories error even with fewer than 53 categories

Tags: r, tree, random-forest, r-factor

I'm trying to make a random forest with the following

```
movies.rf <- randomForest(Infl.Adj.Dom.BoxOffice~. -Genre -Source -ProductionMethod -CreativeType, data=Movies, subset=train)
```

I get

```
Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : Can not handle categorical predictors with more than 53 categories.
```

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678420/classification-tree-in-r-limit-to-32-levels) I tried to check the values of my variables and got this

```
>length(unique(Movies$Genre))
[1] 12
> length(unique(Movies$Source))
[1] 16
> length(unique(Movies$ProductionMethod))
[1] 5
> length(unique(Movies$CreativeType))
[1] 9
```

Individually, none of them is greater than 53, and added together, they are less than 53. So why do I still get the error?

Comment: Maybe there's another variable that you think is numeric but was inadvertently imported as a factor.

Comment: Yes you provided too little info. Examples generally have to be reproducible (see the MCVE requirement) but even that aside we can't even see the variables in the model since you used a `.` on the right hand side

Comment: OK I'll tell you what to do. Re-run it with ONLY the variables you listed in this question as predictors. I will bet 1000 to 1 that the error goes away. So just inspect your data to find the bad column you've thrown in.

Answer (score 0):

If, as it seems from the context of your question, you intend to use only these four features (`Genre, Source, ProductionMethod, CreativeType`) in order to predict `Infl.Adj.Dom.BoxOffice`, then you are using the R formula in a wrong way: your usage

```
Infl.Adj.Dom.BoxOffice~. -Genre -Source -ProductionMethod -CreativeType
```

in fact says "predict `Infl.Adj.Dom.BoxOffice` using all features (`.`) **except** `Genre, Source, ProductionMethod, CreativeType`" (the `-` symbol is used for [*excluding*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580379/how-do-i-exclude-specific-variables-from-a-glm-in-r) variables).

So, what actually happens here, is that one (or more) of your *other* features is a categorical one with more than 53 levels.

The correct usage, if indeed you want to use only these four features you mention, should be:

```
movies.rf <- randomForest(Infl.Adj.Dom.BoxOffice ~ Genre + Source + ProductionMethod + CreativeType, data=Movies, subset=train)
```